# How to add multiple dropdown values and normal text into a texbox

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a email subject textbox where I can input combination of dynamic dropdown value and  other text entered by user, here I can enter only one dynamic value at start, cant add another dynamic value after that please help.

its an email subject for example there are 3 dynamic value here ["creditcard","accountno","Amount"]. 
sample output - "Hi jack your creditcard with accoutno has due Amount" here creditcard accoutno and Amount are dynamic value from dropdown and rest are normal text

**HTML**

```
 <div class="textbox">
        <label class="textbox__label" [for]="id">{{label}}</label>
        <input class="textbox__input" [type]="type" [id]="id" [placeholder]="placeholder" [value]="value" [name]="name"
            autocomplete="off" (input)="onChange($event)" (keyup.Space)="doSomething()" [(ngModel)]="model" />
        <ul class="textbox__dropdown" *ngIf="show">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let list of listData ; let i = index">
                <li (click)="handleSetValue(list)">
                    <span [style.background-color]="colors[i % colors.length]">{{list.value.charAt(0)}}</span>
                    {{list.value}}
                </li>
            </ng-container>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, VERSION,Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  public dynamicList = ["creditcard","accountno","Amount"]
  public value;
 public listData: any;
  public show: boolean = true;
  public model: any;
    @Output() selectedValue = new EventEmitter();


  onChange(event: any) {
    if (event.target.value !== '' && this.dynamicList) {
      console.log(event.target.value);
      this.show = true;
      const item = this.dynamicList.filter((items) => items.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value));
      if (!isEmpty(item)) {
        this.listData = item;
        console.log(item)
      } else {
        this.show = false;
        this.selectedValue.emit(event.target.value)
      }
    } else {
      this.listData = this.dynamicList;
      this.show = false
    }
  }
```

[Stackblitz-link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jffzhz)

Comment: You mean like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vzzsxf

Comment: no i can have all the dynamic values into textbox, right now i can add only one dynamic value

Comment: You are making ```this.show = false;``` so the dropdown values are getting hidden .. Can you explain in detail about your expected result?

Comment: its an email subject for example there are 3 dynamic value here ["creditcard","accountno","Amount"]. 
eg: of textbox content - "Hi jack your creditcard with accoutno has due Amount"
here creditcard accoutno and Amount are dynamic value from dropdown and rest are normal text

Comment: Each time user enter a space I have to check for dynamic value

Comment: Can you check here? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zezntj  .. You would get the suggestions whenever you make a space key event..

Comment: Does this solve your issue?

Comment: yes its working fine.. but after I enter space drowndown comes, but the filter option is missing. You can see first when I enter some text it filter the dropdown and shows, but this is missing in second instance. Rest is working as per requirement... Thanks

Comment: Posted as an answer with the coverage of above said scenario and hope this solves your issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the `event.target.value` that you are making in `onChange()` method like,

```
const getLastSearch = event.target.value.split(' ');
```

Then in the `filter` method you can use the last recent search into `includes` to check and display the latest search result like,

```
const item = this.dynamicList.filter((items) => items.toLowerCase().includes(getLastSearch[getLastSearch.length - 1]));
```

In **app.component.html** , for the input box you could use space bar event and call a method to show the dropdown items like,

```
<input class="textbox__input" type="type" id="id" name="name"
        autocomplete="off" (input)="onChange($event)" (keyup.Space)= "spaceEvent($event)" [(ngModel)]="model" />
```

And the `spaceEvent()` as follows,

```
   spaceEvent(event: any){
    this.listData = this.dynamicList;
    this.show = true;
  }
```

Then finally you could split the strings available in the text box and then you can join it by removing the last one and append the clicked list item to as the last item like,

```
  handleSetValue(list) {
    let splittedSearch = this.model.split(' ');       // Split each string with space
    splittedSearch[splittedSearch.length - 1] = '';   // Make the last string empty
    splittedSearch = splittedSearch.join(' ')         // Join all the splitted string with space
    splittedSearch += list;                           // Concat the splitted search with the selected list item
    this.model =  splittedSearch;                    // Assign the splittedsearch to model
    this.show = false;
  }
```

> [**Forked Stackblitz here...**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-parcs5)

Answer (score 0):

Please make the changes as per [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-list) 
. In TS file

```
public model: any = "";
onChange(event: any) {
    var value = event.target.value;
    var inputarray = value.split(" ");
    var lastinput = inputarray[inputarray.length - 1]
    console.log(lastinput)
    if ((value !== '' || inputarray.length> 1) && this.dynamicList) {
      console.log(value);
      this.show = true;
      const item = this.dynamicList.filter((items) => items.toLowerCase().includes(lastinput));
      if (!isEmpty(item)) {
        this.listData = item;
        console.log(item)
      } else {
        this.show = false;
        this.selectedValue.emit(value)
      }
    } else {
      this.listData = this.dynamicList;
      this.show = false
    }
  }
  handleSetValue(list) {
    debugger
    if(this.dynamicList.find(s=>s == list)){
    this.model += " "+list;
    }
    this.show = false;
    // this.selectedValue.emit(list.key)
  }
```

in HTML

```
<div class="textbox">
    <input class="textbox__input" type="type" id="id" name="name"
     [ngModel]="model"   autocomplete="off" (input)="onChange($event)"/>
    <ul class="textbox__dropdown" *ngIf="show">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let list of listData">
            <li (click)="handleSetValue(list)">
                {{list}}
            </li>
        </ng-container>
    </ul>
</div>
```